# Trigger a flow using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, power-automate

I have Microsoft flow which triggers When an HTTP Request is Received. I want to trigger this flow from the C# code. I tried the following code to trigger the flow but it is not working. The flow didn't get triggered and the code remains in the running state.

```
    private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task NewMethod()
        {
var url = "https://prod-06.australiasoutheast.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/15702797187b4ffcbe386f714f532a8a/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=pOBhhzWW9cUel9v2jfyCUIY5wt4c1o84ezvMBNoLGm4";
            var client = new HttpClient();
           
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
         
        }
```

I also need to pass the parameter to flow from code. What is wrong with the code or do I need to do anything in flow to trigger from outside application?

Comment: Is the Http trigger method set to Get or Post in the flow?

Comment: It is set to Get.

Answer (score 0):

Consider verifying that the Flow id `15702797187b4ffcbe386f714f532a8a` is a valid flow. You may have transposed the id or are using the incorrect API version number associated with that id.

Comment: The URL which I provided is not real.